# How do I get records from starting at 12 o clock on specified days?

Tags: java, sql-server, dateadd

Hey I'm running sql server & inside my where clause I have about 6 of these conditions for different date ranges. The dateadd functions work great, maybe too good in my case. I am missing records because inside the DB if the record has a timestamp for prior than the current time I am running it doesn't get caught. Can I specify my date range (27-33) days and say starting at 12 o clock a.m today instead of the current time?

i.e: A record belonging to March 11, 2014 meets the 27 day range. But it's actually inside DB as

March 11, 2014 4:00:00 Which wont get retrieved bc it's after 4 am.

```
+ "where "
+ "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,27,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
+ "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,33,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "
```

Comment: Dates and DBs are the bane of my existence.  First, let me say that using a function like `dateadd()` through the MS JDBC driver can cause havoc. The way that the SQL gets ran works different than how it works through the Studio Management client.  It caused a very innocuous SQL statement to bring down my Prod environment because the plan optimizer worked differently, so be careful.  For your problem, what you will need to do is drop the time portion to `00:00:00.000`.  There are ways to do it in SQL using `dateadd()`, but I would recommend moving that into your Java code.

Comment: or simply `CAST(Field AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data between range of date using DATE_FORMAT and BETWEEN keyword:

DATE_FORMAT(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate,'%Y-%m-%d') between DATE_FORMAT('" + date1 + "','%Y-%m-%d')
 and DATE_FORMAT('" + date2 + "','%Y-%m-%d')

It may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the code it's huge I'm trying to minimize the burden on Java and use as much as SQL server as possible ... Date format and the other pertaining to dropping the hours mins & seconds sound promising I'll report back around 10a.m. EST

Comment: Guys I have limited internet access but I just read that Covert takes an optional 3rd parameter that should give me what style I want the date in I'll update soon

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate timstamps on java side

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 27);
    Timestamp ts1 = new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
    Timestamp ts2 = new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

and then use them as parameters in PreparedStatement

```
...b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate between ? and ?

ps.setTimestamp(1, ts1);
ps.setTimestamp(2, ts2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your filter (WHERE clause) to two:

At first you get all data by date:

`CAST(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate as date) BETWEEN dateadd(day,27,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND dateadd(day,33,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))`

And then by time

```
CAST(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate as time) BETWEEN '12:00:00' and '23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting 12:00AAM in other words Time is irelevant and all you care is as long as the date is same. 
in this case you can Cast the field and getdate() function to as date and then compare the values in sql server something like

```
WHERE CAST(Field AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```